# OpenCL online compilation: get assembly from cl::program or cl::kernel

Tags: assembly, compilation, opencl

I'm running kernel benchmarks with OpenCL. I know that I can compile kernels offline with various tools from OpenCL vendors (i.e. `ioc64` or `poclcc`). The problem is that I get performance results that I cannot explain with the assembly from these tools, the OpenCL runtime overhead or similar.

I would like to see the assembly of online compiled kernels that are compiled and executed by my benchmark program. **Any ways to do that?**

My approach is to get this assembly somewhere from the `cl::program` or `cl::kernel` objects but I haven't found any way to do that. I appreciate your advice or solutions.

Comment: This is implementation-specific. You'll need to track down how to do this (if at all possible) for each hardware/software combination you want to investigate.

Answer (score 5):

For Intel Graphics you can use `clGetKernelInfo(...,CL_KERNEL_BINARY_PROGRAM_INTEL,...)` to directly get the kernel ISA bits.  To disassemble those bits, you can get the latest GEN ISA disassembler and build it as described [here](https://github.com/intel/opencl-intercept-layer/blob/master/docs/kernel_isa.md).  Specifically, see the section on `Building an Intel GPU ISA Disassembler`.   I haven't used it in a while, but The Intel OpenCL SDK used to do a better job (not a GUI person).  And [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-gen-assembly) is a good article on how to use that tool to scrutinize the assembly.

For NVidia, the "binary" returned by `clGetProgramInfo(...CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES...)` actually returns ptx.  This might be enough, but if you want the exact shader assembly executed, then you can actually feed the ptx into `ptxas` and then disassemble `cuobjdump` with the `--dump-sass` option to get the lowest level assembly.  Note, we're reduced to guessing that the NVidia driver is using the same algorithm as `ptxas`, but it seems logical.

AMD likely has similar tools, but I am less versed on them.

Answer (score 1):

in `clBuildProgram` call you can pass compiler options.

1. Include path with -I
2. Flags with -D
3. Force compiler to drop assembly files with **-save-temps**

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `-save-temps`, which is a [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) and [CLANG](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) option. I tried this option with Intel and POCL but all I get is "Unrecognized/Invalid build option". POCL uses LLVM in the background, that is why I'm a bit confused. However, the internet says it works with AMD.