# How to get assembly code for OpenCL kernel on AMD GPU with OSX

Tags: macos, opencl, amd-gpu

I am trying to view the assembly code of an OpenCL kernel that runs on the AMD GPU of my Mac.

Based on this SO question, [OpenCL online compilation: get assembly from cl::program or cl::kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519918/opencl-online-compilation-get-assembly-from-clprogram-or-clkernel), I used --save-temps to my clBuildProgram call, as below.

err = clBuildProgram(program, num_devices, deviceList, "-save-temps", NULL, NULL);

However, this fails with error code -43, which translates to CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS. Based on https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html, it looks like this option is not supported by the spec.

Tools such as CodeXL shader/kernel analyzer, do not have installation options for Mac.

Is there any other way to see the assembly code for an OpenCL kernel for AMD GPU on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `clGetProgramInfo` with `CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES` to get the "binary" for your platform. It is device/platform specific, and may wrap the machine code in some wrapper structure.